# Trying to follow .AddService & .UseService pattern

Tags: asp.net-core-7.0

In my Minimal API, I use and integrate with Kofax TotalAgility WCF endpoints. I wanted to implement this integration properly, so I added a remote assembly and added the WCF contract in it along with the service interface and implementation:

**Service Interface:**

```csharp
public interface IKofaxService
{
    public Task<string> CreateJob(long letterId);
    public Task ActionHandler(PortalActionRequest request);
}
```

**Service implementation:**

```csharp
public class KofaxService : IKofaxService
{
    private readonly ILogger<KofaxService> logger;
    private readonly KofaxSetup            config;

    private readonly KtaJob.IJobService           jobService;
    private readonly KtaActivity.IActivityService activityService;

    public KofaxService(ILogger<KofaxService> inLogger, KofaxSetup inConfig)
    {
        logger = inLogger;
        // Here is the problem: THe constructor's parameter should be IOptions<Kofaxsetup> instead of just KofaxSetup and this below line will become:
        // config = inConfig.Value;
        config = inConfig;

        //WCF Generated Stuff within this remote assembly
        jobService      = new KtaJob.JobServiceClient(GetBinding(), GetEndpointAddress(config.KtaUrlApiJob)); 
        activityService = new KtaActivity.ActivityServiceClient(GetBinding(), GetEndpointAddress(config.KtaUrlApiActivity));
    }

    public async Task<string> CreateJob(long letterId)
    {
        ...
    }

    public async Task ActionHandler(PortalActionRequest request)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In order to have a `Servces.AddKofaxTotalAgility()` like fluent API, I added the extension method like so (in the remote assembly):
Service extension method:

```csharp
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddKofaxTotalAgility(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IKofaxService, KofaxService>();
        return services;
    }
}
```

Also in the remote assembly, I have a class representing the setting object from appSetting's section:

**Config class:**

```csharp
public class KofaxSetup
{
    public string KtaUrlApiActivity { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string KtaUrlApiJob      { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string SessionId         { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ProcessId         { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Back in the Minimal API project, I added a reference to the remote assembly and also have the settings in `appSettings.json` file:

**appSettings.json:**

```json
{
  ...  
  "KofaxSetup": {
    "KtaUrlApiActivity": "https://kofax.somewhere.com/TotalAgility/Services/SDK/ActivityService.svc",
    "KtaUrlApiJob": "https://kofax.somewhere.com/TotalAgility/Services/SDK/JobService.svc",
    "SessionId": "7DB87F70018D4770BF6114B1C9BA6041",
    "ProcessId": "66EC6EED5D024E7AB0013D60F7A04A1A"
  },
  ...
}
```

Lastly, modifications to `Program.cs` are as follows:
**Minimal API Program.cs**

```csharp
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
// Trigger KofaxSetting object from AppSetting's section
builder.Services.Configure<KofaxSetup>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(KofaxSetup)));
...
// Add the service to the DI
builder.Services.AddKofaxTotalAgility();
...
```

All of this just results in this exception at startup:

**Exception @ var app = builder.Build();**

```
System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: DACRL.Integrations.Kofax.IKofaxService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: DACRL.Integrations.Kofax.KofaxService': Unable to resolve service for type 'DACRL.Integrations.Kofax.Configs.KofaxSetup' while attempting to activate 'DACRL.Integrations.Kofax.KofaxService'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: DACRL.Application.Core.Services.ILetterService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: DACRL.Api.Services.LetterService': Unable to resolve service for type 'DACRL.Integrations.Kofax.Configs.KofaxSetup' while attempting to activate 'DACRL.Integrations.Kofax.KofaxService'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: DACRL.Application.Core.Services.ILetterService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: DACRL.Api.Services.LetterService': Unable to resolve service for type 'DACRL.Integrations.Kofax.Configs.KofaxSetup' while attempting to activate 'DACRL.Integrations.Kofax.KofaxService'.)'

1/2:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: DACRL.Integrations.Kofax.IKofaxService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: DACRL.Integrations.Kofax.KofaxService': Unable to resolve service for type 'DACRL.Integrations.Kofax.Configs.KofaxSetup' while attempting to activate 'DACRL.Integrations.Kofax.KofaxService'.

2/2:
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'DACRL.Integrations.Kofax.Configs.KofaxSetup' while attempting to activate 'DACRL.Integrations.Kofax.KofaxService'.
```

Note that the ILetterService is working properly, and this is the service that internally attempts to receive the IKofaxService from DI in its parameter. I'm thinking the error has something to do with the object KofaxSetup

Is there a best practice that I'm missing here? Am I supposed to have a parameter-less constructor somewhere? Is the `Logger<KofaxService>` injection within the service's implementation not valid?

Answer (score 0):

I actually sorted the issue out but didn't want to waste a well-written question.

The problem was fact, the `KofaxSetup` class. I was receiving it as its type directly in the Service's constructor. I had to use `IOptions<KofaxSetup>` instead to solve the issue.